# Module not found: Can't resolve 'reactfire' in '

Tags: firebase, reactjs

instale el reactfire para las firebase pero ahora me manda este error
no se su falte algo mas de instalar pero utilize 
-npm install  --save firebase react@next para instalarlo 
Error que aparece 
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'reactfire' in 'C:\Users\jesus\myapp\src'

Estoy utilizando react js 
codigo index.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Edit from './components/Edit';
import Create from './components/Create';
import Show from './components/Show';
import Vista from './components/Vista';
import Createcomentarios from './components/Createcomentarios';
import Indexpublico from './components/Indexpublico';
import Createviaje from './components/Createviaje';
import VistaComentarios from './components/VistaComentarios';
import Editviaje from './components/Editviaje';
import Showviaje from './components/Showviaje';
import Nosotrospublico from './components/Nosotrospublico';
import rutaspublico from './components/rutaspublico';
import viajeadmon from './components/viajeadmon';
import Appcss from './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,} from "react-router-dom";
import firebaseConfig from'./firebase-config';
import{FirebaseAppProvider} from 'reactfire';


ReactDOM.render(
(
    <Router>
    <div>
    <FirebaseAppProvider  firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
        <Suspense fallback={'esperando'}>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
                <Route path='/edit/:id' component={Edit} />
                <Route path='/create' component={Create} />
                <Route path='/vista' component={Vista} />
                <Route path='/indexpublico' component={Indexpublico} />
                <Route path='/show/:id' component={Show} />
                <Route path='/Createcomentarios' component={Createcomentarios} />
                <Route path='/VistaComentarios' component={VistaComentarios} />
                <Route path='/viajeadmon' component={viajeadmon} />
                <Route path='/Editviaje/:id' component={Editviaje} />
                <Route path='/Createviaje' component={Createviaje} />
                <Route path='/Showviaje/:id' component={Showviaje} />
                <Route path='/rutaspublico' component={rutaspublico} />
                <Route path='/Nosotrospublico' component={Nosotrospublico} />
        </Suspense>
    </FirebaseAppProvider>    
    </div>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: Estuve viendo la dependencia en npm.js y ahi dice que esta dependencia esta en un estado experimental.. no me sorprenderia si te diera ese tipo de problemas

Answer (score 0):

ejecutaste esto: `npm install --save firebase react@next`

pero debe ser : `npm install --save firebase reactfire@next`

Espero te sirva